# Rounding in double java

Tags: java

```
public class project3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int earnedRuns = 52;
        int inningsPitched = 182;
        double ERA = (earnedRuns * 9) / inningsPitched;
        String FirstName = "Anibal";
        String LastName = "Sanchez";

        System.out.println("Pitcher's first name: " + FirstName);
        System.out.println("Pitcher's last name: " + LastName);
        System.out.println("Number of earned runs: " + earnedRuns);
        System.out.println("Number of innings pitched: " + inningsPitched);
        System.out.println(FirstName + " " + LastName + " has an ERA of " + ERA);
    }
}
```

The ERA comes out as `2.0` not `2.57`... ect
I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baically you're:

1. multiplying an **integer** by an **integer** -> **integer** *(Result: 486)*
2. dividing an **integer** by an **integer** -> **integer** *(Result: 2)*
3. Assign the result to an **double variable** -> **double**  *(Result: 2.0D)*

So you first need to **cast** ("convert") those integers to floats or doubles.

```
double ERA = ((double)earnedRuns * 9) / inningsPitched;
```

or simpler:

```
double ERA = (earnedRuns * 9.0) / inningsPitched;
```

It's enough to cast just one integer because in java: integer * double -> double

EDIT:

The 9.0 **D** or 9.0 **d** just tells java that explicitly that 9.0 is meant to be a **double**.
The same also works for 9.0 **f** or 9.0 **F**. This means that 9.0 is a **float**.

Comment: thank you. it was telling me to change the integers to doubles as well but that was not the assignment.

Comment: np and don't forget if the answer was helpful, accept it as answer :D